# Create empty csv with headings with Powershell when data not available in database table

Tags: powershell, csv, export

I am currently creating a powershell script that exports data from database tables to csv files. My script is working but if there is no data in the tables then I am getting empty csvs. However, when there is no data I still require the csv with just headers. How can I amend the current script to do this?

```
$server = "SERVERNAME"
$database = "DATABASENAME"
$tablequery = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM [PUB_FINANCE].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='gdm' AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'mapping%'
AND TABLE_TYPE != 'VIEW'"
$fileDirectory = "C:\export\AnaCredit\"

#Delcare Connection Variables
$connectionTemplate = "Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog={1};"
$connectionString = [string]::Format($connectionTemplate, $server, $database)
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
 
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$command.CommandText = $tablequery
$command.Connection = $connection
 
#Load up the Tables in a dataset
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$connection.Close()

# Loop through all tables and export a CSV of the Table Data
foreach ($Row in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    $queryData = "SELECT * FROM [PUB_FINANCE].[gdm].[$($Row[0])]"
     
    #Specify the output location of your dump file
    $extractFile = "C:\export\AnaCredit\$($Row[0]).csv"
     
    $command.CommandText = $queryData
    $command.Connection = $connection
 
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    $connection.Close()
    $DataSet.Tables[0]  | Export-Csv $extractFile -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: Query the schema for the column names (eg. `SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ... `), then create a dummy object and generate CSV header from that (eg. `$columnNames |% {$properties = [ordered]@{}} { $properties[$_] = "" } { [pscustomobject]$properties} |ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |Select -First 1`)